# overloading an operator

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and trying to understand the concepts of overloading.

Comment: Can you give an example of "redefining an operator" or where you've seen it? That's not a common term.

Comment: You cannot generally redefine anything in C++, because of the One Definition Rule, which says that everything may be defined at most once.

Answer (score 2):

"Operator overloading" is the common term for providing a custom implementation for one of the C++ operators.

It's known as "overloading" because, *in some scenarios*, you are conceptually overloading a function `operator@` (where `@` is some operator symbol) with a new overload that takes an object of your custom type as an argument.

```
/**
 * Doesn't actually exist in this form, but conceptually
 * this exists built in to the language.
 */
int operator+(int, int);

/**
 * Your overload of the `operator+` function, which takes
 * `MyClass`s.
 */
MyClass operator+(const MyClass&, const MyClass&);
```

The term becomes inaccurate when you start defining operators as *members* of your types, because `MyClass::operator+` does not overload `::operator+`; at best it'll hide it (e.g. ADL) and at worst it's just a better match during name lookup. But, "operator overloading" has stuck anyway.

Conversely, if you tried to outright redefine an existing operator overload then your compiler and/or linker would prevent the build from succeeding, so "redefining an operator" is not an accepted term for anything that works.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, there is no such thing as redefining an operator. The operators are there, and we are allowed to overload most of them.